# How to test if state are being set in Enzyme and Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm new to using Jest and Enzyme. I have a component that sets some props which are passed down from a parent component. Depending on the API call invoked, I want to ensure that these props are set accordingly. In this code I want to test that the `setUser` for my `user`  was properly called. Here is my code:

LoginButton.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import './LoginButton.css';

const LoginButton = (props) => {

  const history = useHistory();

  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  const login = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const loginRequest = {
      userName: props.username,
      password: props.password
    };
    try {
      const loginResponse = await fetch('/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(loginRequest),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
      });
      const user = await loginResponse.json();
      console.log("User: ", user);
      if (user.status && user.message) {
        props.setSubmitError(user.message);
      } else if (user.userStatus && user.userStatus === "Locked" || user.userStatus === "Deactivated") {
        props.setSubmitError(user.message);
      } else {
        setUser(user);
        // TODO: do something with user, pass it to dashboard component
        history.push('/dashboard');
      }
    } catch (err) {
      props.setSubmitError(user.message);
    }
  }

  return (
    <button styleName="sign-in-btn" onClick={login}>
      Sign me in!
    </button>
  )
}

export default LoginButton;
```

And here is my attempt to do so in LoginButton.test.js:

```
// mock useHistory or else it will fail in every test
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  useHistory: () => ({
    push: jest.fn()
  })
}));

describe('LoginButton', () => {
  const setUser = jest.fn();
  const useStateSpy = jest.spyOn(React, 'useState');
  useStateSpy.mockImplementation((init) => [init, setUser]);

  it('sets user state properly', () => {

    let props = {
      setSubmitError: jest.fn()
    }

    const fakeResponse = {userName: "user123",  success: true};
    const mockJsonPromise = Promise.resolve(fakeResponse);
    const mockFetchPromise = Promise.resolve({
      json: () => {
        mockJsonPromise
      }
    });

    global.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(mockFetchPromise);
    const wrapper = shallow(<LoginButton
      {...props} 
    />);
    const signInButton = wrapper.find('button')
    signInButton.simulate('click', {
      preventDefault: () => {},
    });
    expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    // here i expect setUser to have been called already.. but I get an error saying number of calls: 0
    expect(setUser).toHaveBeenCalledWith(fakeResponse);

    global.fetch.mockClear();
    delete global.fetch;

  });
})
```

I unfortunately get an error saying that setUser was never called and I'm not sure why. I feel like I setup the test properly and depending on the `fakeResponse` I passed in, I believe it should go into m `else` statement and set the user properly. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: don't.

You don't need to test `setUser`. That's an implementation detail, and internal to the component. You can test that the `setSubmitError` callback or `history.push` were called, if that seems useful (you'll probably also need an `onSuccess` handler to pass up the returned user, so you could test that as well). But testing a purely internal implementation like a state setter violates the principle of [black box testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing).

If you really want to get that specific in testing the `login` function, consider extracting it as a helper function, which can be tested outside of the context of the component. That makes it more clear what the expected outputs are for given inputs.